# My Jquery UI dialog doesn't fire if not preceded by an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, alert, jquery-ui-dialog

My problem is I have a Jquery UI dialog which not fire if not preceded by an alert.

The div for my dialog at the beginning of my page :

```
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Modification de la date de fin du projet">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Keep or change ?</p>
</div>
```

The event which fire the dialog :

```
  nameInput.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 10)
    {
      alert("ok");
      $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
  });
```

My Jquery UI dialog :

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: true,
      height:190,
      width:450,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Keep": function() {

          keep();

          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Change": function() {

          change();

          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
```

I searched and tried many different ways (like using document.ready for example, etc...) but it doesn't did the trick.

Comment: This `$(function() {` IS document ready, https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my own problem.
It was because I doesn't have added `event.preventDefault();` after the :

```
if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 10) { ... }
```

The dialog only opens if the user type Enter on his keyboard (the keys 13 and 10 are for the Enter button), and so, the dialog instantly closes because the user type Enter and the first button of the dialog is focused, so that Enter key trigger the first button, and the dialog closes after the execution of the fist button code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to pass the event object to the event handler of `nameInput`. The alert call should have nothing to do with that.

It should look like this:

```
nameInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { // forgot event param here
    if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 10)
        {
            // alert("ok");
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
        }
});
```

Comment: The event param is inferred and so I don't have to add it.

Comment: @testaabalez Only to make this clear to me. Where do you infer the event param from?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and added a delay. Try:

```
$("#dialog-confirm" ).delay(2000).dialog("open");
```

Comment: When you encounter a "I had to add a delay" most often it means something needs changed elsewhere or you are improperly handling something.

Comment: I didn't like it either, but I had to get it to work. In my case I had to wait to display what I got from the server.

Comment: Then you should consider the promise and display within that event.